# ASP.NET MVC passing whole model to controller using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

How can I pass view's Model to controller using ajax? Please see JS function CreateTable() below:

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    //CODE FOR GETTING STUFF HERE

    return View(viewModel);
}

public JsonResult GetResult(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    //CODE FOR GETTING STUFF HERE

    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        aaData = viewModel.Data,
        iTotalRecords = viewModel.Data.Rows.Count,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = viewModel.DisplayRecords
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here's the ajax part for the datatables.net processing:

```
function CreateTable() {
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "deferRender": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetResult")",
        "fnServerParams": function (aaData) {
            //here's my problem: HOW CAN I PUSH MY WHOLE MODEL HERE?
            aaData.push({ "name": "MyViewModel", "value": "@Model" });
        },
        "sPaginationType": "simple_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "oLanguage": { "sProcessing": "Loading..." },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sName": "Col1" },
            { "sName": "Col2" },
            { "sName": "Col3" },
            { "sName": "Col3" },
            { "sName": "Col4" },
            { "sName": "Col5" }
        ]
    });
}
```

My friend told me that I can also pass the whole Model from ajax to my controller but I'm not sure how to do that. Please advise what is the better way to implement this. Thank you.

Comment: You need to serialise your model to JSON if you want to use it in javascript. Using Json.net you would use something like `@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)`

Comment: I am trying Alex's answer below same as yours, but I am having Compilation Error with JsonConvert

Comment: You need to get the `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package for the JsonConvert to be recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [fnServerParams](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerParams) you use `aoData.push` to send custom parameters to the server. I'm not sure about passing the entire model as a single parameter, but you can do it like this:

```
aoData.push({ "name": "customParam1", "value": $('#param1').val() });
aoData.push({ "name": "customParam2", "value": $('#param2').val() });
```

where `param1` and `param2` are model properties retrieved from jQuery selectors.

Your controller method needs to retrieve these parameters from the querystring.  Something like this:

Create a model that represents the custom parameters (this would basically replicate `MyViewModel` in your example):

```
public class MyCustomParamModel
{
    public string customParam1 { get; set; }
    public string customParam2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, parse the querystring, get the custom params and assign them to your model

```
public JsonResult GetResult(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());

    var model = new MyCustomParamModel
    {
        customParam1 = qs["customParam1"],
        customParam2 = qs["customParam2"],
    }
```

Now you have your model data in the controller and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks, I get the point here. But what if I have a property of MyCustomParamModel as DataTable? How can I do that? Let's say MyCustomParamModel.customParam1 is a datatable?

Comment: I think you'd have to pass it as an array, or stringify it somehow, I'm not really sure how or why you'd do this.  Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your model with  `@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))` so your function will look like:

```
"fnServerParams": function (aaData) {

            aaData.push({ name: "viewModel", value: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)) });
        },
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your time on checking my problem, and how can I catch that with my controller GetResult() ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. MVC model binder will resolve this model. Just use your `viewModel`  object in the method. It will have all the values  that you passed from client

Comment: JsonConvert returns Compilation Error from my end. :(

Comment: You mean `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)` returns a compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you pass the json object with the same properties as your model, you should be home safe, eg:

```
Model:

public class Language
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Language1{ get; set; }
        public string Language2 { get; set; }
    }

Ajax:

$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ID: 1,
                Language1: "English",
                Language2: "German",
                         }),
            dataType: 'json',


            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
```